# SQL Server 2008 - Computed Column Extract Only Numeric From Other Column

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008. Is there a way I can create computed column (deterministic) by extracting only numerical value from another alphanumeric column in the same table? and then index it?

For example, in my table `tblVendorShippingInfo` I have a column `PONum` what is alphanumeric, data type `VARCHAR`.

I tried to create a function and added the column (below)

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Calc_GetPOID] (@strText VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Left(@strText, 8) ) > 0
    BEGIN   
        SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText), 1, '')
    END
    RETURN Left(@strText,8)
END

-- Add the computed column 
ALTER TABLE tblVendorShippingInfo 
    ADD POID AS dbo.[Calc_GetPOID](PONum)
```

When I tried to add an index for POID computed column, it prompted error something related to "cannot add because it is non-deterministic column"...

Any suggestions to make it deterministic and indexable?

Comment: Are the "alpha" guaranteed to be Latin alphabet. If so you could use 26 nested replaces rather than looking for all non numeric in a loop in a scalar UDF. Or you could just add `SCHEMABINDING` to your existing function.

Comment: It is not always Latin aphabet, sometime it contains special characters like `,$,&,@,!,',",+....`. So if I use  `SCHEMABINDING`, I should be able to index that column? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Yep. Your function doesn't access any data or use non deterministic functions so it will be recognised as deterministic as here http://rextester.com/USM49231

Comment: It works.  Thank you so much for helping.